# A flexible menu function in python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

This is a question about some code I've written that works, but I'm not sure it's *good* code.

I would like to get some comments on this or if possible hints to build a better solution.

**Background:**

This is a small program to calculate some data, connect these to a participant and store it in a JSON file.

Here the already working solution:

```
menu_entries = (
                    ('Order Pizza', order_pizza),
                    ('Order Burger', order_burger),
                    ('Order Coke', order_coke, '0.5')
               )


def menu(menu_title, menu_entries):

    while True:
        mpoint = 0

        print(menu_title)

        # Build the menu entries plus one to close
        for entry in menu_entries:
            mpoint += 1
            print(str(mpoint) + '.', entry[0])

        print(str(mpoint + 1) + '.', 'Ende')

        # Get value and validate
        try:
            task = int(input('> '))
        except ValueError:
            task = None

        if task is None or task > mpoint + 1:
            task = None
            continue

        if task == mpoint + 1:
            print('Done')
            break

        # Build a function call
        get_task = menu_entries[task - 1][1]
        try:
            get_task(menu_entries[task - 1][2])
        except IndexError:
            get_task()


def order_pizza(size=None):
    if size is None:
        size = ''
    print('Bring me a Pizza!')


def order_burger(size=None):
    if size is None:
        size = ''
    print('One {} Burger please.'.format(size))


def order_coke(size=None):
    if size is None:
        size = ''
    print('A {} Coke please.'.format(size))


menu('Main menu', menu_entries)
```

As you can see the menu function gets a main title and a tuple of menu entries.

In these menu entries I could define the menu point title, a function name and *one* parameter.

All these other functions are only examples and are of no interest (they are ugly, I know).

Please have a look, criticize and if possible show me a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an actual error in your code:

```
$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    ('Order Pizza', order_pizza),
NameError: name 'order_pizza' is not defined
```

You need to define `menu_entries` *after* creating the things it refers to.

Some notes:

1. All Python code could benefit from being run through at least one **linter** such as flake8 or pycodestyle. Nothing springs out at me except possibly the indentation of `menu_entries`, but it's worth a check.
2. Generally, names don't need to repeat anything which is understood from context. So `def menu(menu_title, menu_entries):` could be easier written as `def menu(title, entries):`
3. You always add one to `mpoint` - a cleaner solution would be to `mpoint = 1` and continue from there. If `mpoint` was used for indexing into an array that would be different, but it's really only for presentation.
4. When reading the code top to bottom I should be able to understand what a name means the first time I encounter it. `mpoint` should be renamed to what it is (maybe `menu_index`?).
5. For consistency (and to write more idiomatic code) the strings in *all* your `print` statements should be `format`ted.
6. This is a prime example for code which could be made object oriented - obvious classes include `Menu`, `MenuEntry` and `Order`.
7. Setting `task = None` and then checking if it's `None` to check whether you should `continue` is redundant - you can just `continue` immediately.
8. `size` is unused in `order_pizza`, so it should be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the notes!

Most of them are clear and I think would be no problem to eliminate.
Point 6 and 8 are the same, right?


One thing about point 7: How to do this with a class?

I'm not really aware how classes work and have not found a good tutorial (don't want to build cars...).

As already mentioned the helper functions are ugly. Only the menu function is relevant.

Comment: None of the SO/SE sites will help you to learn foundational skills like OO ([by design](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/)), and I'm afraid I can't give any good pointers to learn it. Sorry.